# Uploading captured image to server in android fails

Tags: php, android, file-upload

I am trying to upload image captured by camera to server using php but on clicking the upload button it goes to previous activity I could not get what the problem is.

here is, UploadActivity.java

```
package com.example.opts;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.example.opts.AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;;

public class UploadActivity extends Activity {
    // LogCat tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private String filePath = null;
    private TextView txtPercentage;
    private ImageView imgPreview;
    private Button btnUpload;
    long totalSize = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.upload_activity);
        txtPercentage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);
        btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);

        // Changing action bar background color


        // Receiving the data from previous activity
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // image or video path that is captured in previous activity
        filePath = i.getStringExtra("filePath");

        // boolean flag to identify the media type, image or video
        boolean isImage = i.getBooleanExtra("isImage", true);

        if (filePath != null) {
            // Displaying the image or video on the screen
            previewMedia(isImage);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry, file path is missing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // uploading the file to server
                new UploadFileToServer().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Displaying captured image/video on the screen
     * */
    private void previewMedia(boolean isImage) {
        // Checking whether captured media is image or video

            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }

    /**
     * Uploading the file to server
     * */
    private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // setting progress bar to zero
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // Making progress bar visible
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // updating progress bar value
            progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

            // updating percentage value
            txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return uploadFile();
        }


        private String uploadFile() {
            String responseString = null;

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

            try {
                MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            if (filePath !=null) {
                                    File file = new File(filePath);
                                    FileBody fb=new FileBody(file);
                                    Log.d("EDIT USER PROFILE", "UPLOAD: file length = " + file.length());
                                    Log.d("EDIT USER PROFILE", "UPLOAD: file exist = " + file.exists());
                                    mpEntity.addPart("image", fb);
                                }

               httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);                
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            }

            return responseString;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);

            // showing the server response in an alert dialog
            showAlert(result);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Method to show alert dialog
     * */
    private void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Response from Servers")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

and fileUpload.php

```
<?php


    // Path to move uploaded files
    $target_path = "uploads/";
    // array for final json response
    $response = array();


    // final file url that is being uploaded
    $file_upload_url = 'http://opts.netne.net/uploads/';


    if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);



        $response['file_name'] = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

        try {
            // Throws exception incase file is not being moved
            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
                // make error flag true
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['message'] = 'Could not move the file!';
            }

            // File successfully uploaded
            $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully!';
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['file_path'] = $file_upload_url . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        // File parameter is missing
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'Not received any file!F';
    }

    // Echo final json response to client
    //echo json_encode($response);
    echo $target_path;
    ?>
```

My app stops responding on using MultiPartEntity in my code. Please provide me a solution to upload captured image to server.

here's the complete logcat

```
    04-11 15:41:20.523: I/clicks(9214): You Clicked B1
04-11 15:41:22.653: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(9214): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/content/AbstractContentBody; (2647)
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/content/AbstractContentBody;' failed
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody; (2297)
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody;' failed
04-11 15:41:28.593: E/dalvikvm(9214): Could not find class 'org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody', referenced from method com.example.opts.UploadActivity$UploadFileToServer.uploadFile
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2299 (Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody;) in Lcom/example/opts/UploadActivity$UploadFileToServer;
04-11 15:41:28.593: D/dalvikvm(9214): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0025
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/content/AbstractContentBody; (2647)
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/content/AbstractContentBody;' failed
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody; (2297)
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody;' failed
04-11 15:41:28.593: D/dalvikvm(9214): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x4291 at 0x27 in Lcom/example/opts/UploadActivity$UploadFileToServer;.uploadFile
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart; (2646)
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart;' failed
04-11 15:41:28.593: E/dalvikvm(9214): Could not find class 'org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart', referenced from method org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.<init>
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2291 (Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart;) in Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity;
04-11 15:41:28.593: D/dalvikvm(9214): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0003
04-11 15:41:28.593: I/dalvikvm(9214): Failed resolving Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ContentBody; interface 2640 'Lorg/apache/james/mime4j/message/Body;'
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ContentBody;' failed
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ContentBody;)
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart; (2646)
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart;' failed
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart; (2641)
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart;' failed
04-11 15:41:28.593: E/dalvikvm(9214): Could not find class 'org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart', referenced from method org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.addPart
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2289 (Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart;) in Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity;
04-11 15:41:28.593: D/dalvikvm(9214): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0002
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart; (2646)
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart;' failed
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart; (2646)
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart;' failed
04-11 15:41:28.593: I/dalvikvm(9214): Could not find method org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.getTotalLength, referenced from method org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.getContentLength
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16997: Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart;.getTotalLength ()J
04-11 15:41:28.593: D/dalvikvm(9214): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart; (2646)
04-11 15:41:28.593: W/dalvikvm(9214): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart;' failed
04-11 15:41:28.603: W/dalvikvm(9214): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart; (2646)
04-11 15:41:28.603: W/dalvikvm(9214): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart;' failed
04-11 15:41:28.603: I/dalvikvm(9214): Could not find method org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.getBodyParts, referenced from method org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.isRepeatable
04-11 15:41:28.613: W/dalvikvm(9214): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16990: Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart;.getBodyParts ()Ljava/util/List;
04-11 15:41:28.623: D/dalvikvm(9214): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-11 15:41:28.623: W/dalvikvm(9214): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart; (2646)
04-11 15:41:28.623: W/dalvikvm(9214): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart;' failed
04-11 15:41:28.623: W/dalvikvm(9214): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart; (2646)
04-11 15:41:28.623: W/dalvikvm(9214): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart;' failed
04-11 15:41:28.623: I/dalvikvm(9214): Could not find method org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.writeTo, referenced from method org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.writeTo
04-11 15:41:28.623: W/dalvikvm(9214): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17002: Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart;.writeTo (Ljava/io/OutputStream;)V
04-11 15:41:28.623: D/dalvikvm(9214): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-11 15:41:28.623: W/dalvikvm(9214): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart; (2646)
04-11 15:41:28.623: W/dalvikvm(9214): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart;' failed
04-11 15:41:28.623: D/dalvikvm(9214): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x425a at 0x07 in Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity;.<init>
04-11 15:41:28.623: D/dalvikvm(9214): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x4cbb at 0x1e in Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity;.<init>
04-11 15:41:28.623: D/dalvikvm(9214): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x4cb7 at 0x25 in Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity;.<init>
04-11 15:41:28.623: W/dalvikvm(9214): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart; (2641)
04-11 15:41:28.623: W/dalvikvm(9214): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart;' failed
04-11 15:41:28.623: D/dalvikvm(9214): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x424e at 0x04 in Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity;.addPart
04-11 15:41:28.623: W/dalvikvm(9214): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x95d33b20)
04-11 15:41:28.623: D/AndroidRuntime(9214): procName from cmdline: com.example.opts
04-11 15:41:28.623: E/AndroidRuntime(9214): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.opts
04-11 15:41:28.623: D/AndroidRuntime(9214): file written successfully with content: com.example.opts StringBuffer : ;com.example.opts
04-11 15:41:28.653: I/Process(9214): Sending signal. PID: 9214 SIG: 9
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214): Process: com.example.opts, PID: 9214
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214):     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.<init>(MultipartEntity.java:77)
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214):     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.<init>(MultipartEntity.java:100)
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214):     at com.example.opts.UploadActivity$UploadFileToServer.uploadFile(UploadActivity.java:158)
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214):     at com.example.opts.UploadActivity$UploadFileToServer.doInBackground(UploadActivity.java:139)
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214):     at com.example.opts.UploadActivity$UploadFileToServer.doInBackground(UploadActivity.java:1)
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-11 15:41:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(9214):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: Do you get anything in `responseString` ?

Comment: It returns to previous activity as soon as I click on upload button in my android emulator and shows app not responding in mobile devices.

Comment: There would be exception log in your logcat. Post the complete logcat in your question.

Comment: Try to use Open Source.
I use ion for file upload/ download
https://github.com/koush/ion